# How do you push a block of text in C to make space and write in a file using low level I/O?

Tags: c, file, unix, file-handling, low-level-io

So I have to write in  a file that already has text in it , using Low Level I/O, but I have to write in the middle of that text so I need to push that text and make space, same strategy for deletion, but I don't have an idea on how to do it . The functions I should use are :

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count); 
ssize_t write(int fd, const char *buf, size_t count);
int close( int handle );
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
off_t lseek(int fildes, off_t offset, int whence);
```

Thank you.

Comment: There's no easy way to do that – you'll need to copy the remainder (the text to be "pushed back") somewhere (memory or another file), then write what you want to write in the middle, then write the pushed-back contents back at the end.

Comment: Note that the file APIs does not allow you to do inserts in the middle of a file (it only allows overwriting existing content or appending to the end of the file). This means you need to rewrite the files, I.e. 1. read from the file up to where you want to insert, 2. write that part to a new file, 3. write your new stuff to the new file 4. Read the remainder of the original file and write that to the new file.